# Why does handBrake rotate my original videos?

Tags: mac, video

**tl;dr** stop hanbrake from rotating my original videos once it compresses them.

I know that similar questions about rotating have been asked, but they are more in the lines of "how do I rotate a video". Mine is a little different.

I could use some of the solutions other question provide to rotate my video, however, my  original video was on the right orientation to start with!

When I compress it with handBrake, it rotates it to the wrong orientation automatically. Why is it doing that? I have a lot of videos, Its so annoying that I have to rotate them back after compressing them. Can I just compress them one with handbrake not have to deal with rotating them back?

Here is a picture of how my handBrake setting are set:

[image]

One thing that kind of "fixes" this is that in quickTime, there is an option to edit the video and it can rotate it but it takes 21 minutes to rotate the newly compressed video! Jesus! The video is not even 1 GB in its compressed form... isn't there a different way of doing this? This actually doesn't work because when I re-saved my video, it increased size dramatically. Its original size was under 1GB and rotating it in quicktime and then saving it increased the size to 5GB. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Ive found a simple way to get round this, is to film all landscape videos with the home button on the right hand side, all portrait videos with the home button at the bottom. Not a solution per say, but a work around

Answer (score 7):

**Why:**
Some programs like quick time, automatic rotate the video when they display, but the original file is still not ok. Please try to see your videos using vlc or other apps. handBrake only rotate your videos if you set that option.

**How:**
You can rotate the video if you fill the **Additional options** in the bottom. If you like to rotate 90 clockwise with "Custom `--rotate=4`" or 90 counter-clockwise with "Custom `--rotate=7`".

the full parameter list is:

- 1 : x flip
- 2 : y flip
- 3 : 180 degrees rotate (also the DEFAULT)
- 4 :90 degrees rotate (clockwise)
- 5 : 90 degrees rotate + y flip
- 6 : 270 degrees rotate + y flip
- 7 : 270 degrees rotate

See similar question on https://superuser.com/questions/418985/can-handbrake-flip-rotate-a-video

Answer (score 4):

That might be caused by iOS video recording issue. Videos are always recorded in landscape, but the orientation of the phone during recording is saved in the movie, so iPhone and probably Apple software rotates the videos during playback, while they are rotated when playing them using any other software. Video converters usually has option to rotate movie and save them so they will played correctly using any player.

> HandBrake (or at least the GUI) does not offer a way to rotate video. The HandBrake CLI does have a "rotate" option, however I found it is not a true rotation. Rather, it simply flips on an axis. The documentation is poor, but I found that a value of 1 flips on X, 2 flips on Y, and 3 flips on X and Y. So using a value of 3 is the same as doing a 180° rotation, which is useful for videos that are upside down, but not for videos that are sideways.

Maybe [this post will help you](http://thom-patterson.com/tags/video-rotation) fix this.

Comment: "Videos are always recorded in landscape". That's just simply not true. If that were the case, [this](http://cheezburger.com/7610919424) [wouldn't](http://gizmodo.com/5915888/an-important-psa-on-why-you-should-never-shoot-videos-vertically) [be](http://www.nj.com/business/index.ssf/2014/07/shooting_video_with_your_phone_dont_hold_it_vertically.html) a [thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt9zSfinwFA).

Comment: Do you mind giving me the exact command I should give CLI so that the original vertical video that I want to compress, is compressed and vertical after handBrake process it?

Comment: @tubedogg He goes to say but the orientation of the phone during recording is saved in the movie.  So if your playback device recognizes the orientation it was saved in it will have the issue like your links. And if handbrake disregards this info - it all fits, and it can be true that all videos are recorded in landscape.